# ¿Cuánto es el límite por usuario para reportar post?

Tags: soporte

¿Cuánto es el límite x usuario para reportar post?
E¿ste número de reportes se recarga con el tiempo?

Ahora mismo me dice que puedo hacer 10 reportes más y ya dudo en reportar o pedir intervención del moderador aunque realmente se que es necesario.

Comment: Hay un artículo de ayuda sobre el tema, el cual está pendiente de traducir: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: creo que son 10 por dia, despues se vuelven a 10 si has usado alguno el dia anterior. Saludos

Comment: Sería bueno que las colocaran como respuesta para poder marcarlas.

Answer (score 3):

De la [documentación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

Inicialmente tienes 10 banderas por día:

- Cada 2k de reputación, una bandera adicional.
- Cada 10 banderas útiles, una bandera adicional.
- El limite total es de 100 banderas.

Por ejemplo: Actualmente, he puesto 39 reportes útiles y tengo 14 banderas por día.

- El sitio principal y el sitio meta, llevan cuentas separadas. Actualmente tengo 11 banderas por día en el sitio meta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Todavía no probé de reportar, es bueno saberlo.